# Checking among multiple values

Tags: java, resultset

I have the below results as part of resultset.

```
Name Dept
John IT
Mike IT
Cathy CS
Julie CS
Aria  Electronics
Shann Electronics
```

I should be able to separate the resultset based on Dept and put the results in a map. E.g: After Mike, the dept changes and hence I should put John and Mike in a map. Then Cathy and Julie in a map and so on. How do I do it?

```
public void loadMap(ResultSet inputResultSet, MbGlobalMap inputTranslationObjMap) throws Exception {

    String key = "";
    List < dept > list = new ArrayList < dept > ();

    while (inputResultSet.next()) {
        String name = inputResultSet.getString(1);
        String key = inputResultSet.getString(2);
        dept d1 = new dept(name, key);
        list.add(d1);
    }

    if (inputTranslationObjMap.containsKey(key)) {
        inputTranslationObjMap.update(key, list);
    } else {
        inputTranslationObjMap.put(key, list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code, English is a terrible programming language.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `true`.

Comment: public void loadMap(ResultSet inputResultSet, MbGlobalMap inputTranslationObjMap) throws Exception {String key =""; List<dept> list = new ArrayList<dept>();while (inputResultSet.next()) {         
         String name = inputResultSet.getString(1);
         String key = inputResultSet.getString(2);
         dept d1 = new dept(name, key);
         
          list.add(d1);
        }
        
        if (inputTranslationObjMap.containsKey(key)) {
         inputTranslationObjMap.update(key, list);
        } else {
         inputTranslationObjMap.put(key, list);
        }
       
            
    }

Comment: Not here, edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this -

```
public void loadMap(ResultSet inputResultSet,
        MbGlobalMap inputTranslationObjMap) throws Exception {
    // String key = "";
    List<dept> list = null;
    while (inputResultSet.next()) {
        String name = inputResultSet.getString(1);
        String key = inputResultSet.getString(2);
        // first check if the map has a list already.
        if (inputTranslationObjMap.containsKey(key)) {
            list = inputTranslationObjMap.get(key);
        } else {
            // No... add a new list to the map.
            list = new ArrayList<dept>();
            inputTranslationObjMap.put(key, list);
        }
        dept d1 = new dept(name, key);
        list.add(d1);
    }
}
```